# How to keep function running even user reloads the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

one of my pages has a controller that initalizes user while getting some data from APIs on first visit. I want to keep function running even user reloads the page at that time. if user reloads or navigates or closes browser or even logs out i want to keep running this function until i complete the data gathering from APIs.

How can i implement this kind of structure with AngularJS & Express JS Backend.

btw, after first visit i will check the db if user initialized or not and dont call the initialize() function again, i will just get data from db and serve to user.

Comment: Client side javascript runs in the browser. If the user closes the browser then your client side script stops running.

Comment: @papakia ok but cant we assign a function running in server with user request and keep running until finishes at the backend. the function gets data from apis and save them in db. After user visits again angular serve the data from db which is completed by the function ?

Answer (score 3):

it's not possible
if you close or refresh your browser connection is lost and may not receive the answer

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i think its possible some how but i dont know exactly :) i am searching to do this in express , like assigning function to run until finishes and at the same time do some http requests.

Comment: It's totally impossible. You cannot force a user to do something if he doesn't want to. A user has to close the page if he doesn't want your scripts to run. Imagine all the attacks this would open. Why do you want to do this anyway?

Comment: let me be more clear, i dont force the user. User has a dashboard that collects information about user from apis, getting lots of data would take minutes i want to assign a function running in the backend, and dont want to keep the user until all data collect. he could navigate through site or even logs out. Only after the function finishes and gets data then user can be able to see data in dashboard. But during the getting data part i dont want to interrupt user yo stay in same page.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the functionality using the `Service Workers`. They don't have a `page` context. They run in `global` scope and doesn't belong to a particular page.

For more information on what Service workers can do, follow this link

[Service Workers/ W3C](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/blob/master/explainer.md)

Comment: thanks, can a service worker works on backend? or does it run in the browser but just without depending a page?

Comment: Your requirement is much similar to push notifications but in different context and usage. Server should push the notification(in your case request) which will, in turn, perform what you need.! P.S: I don't have much knowledge on this. Please do R&D. There are many examples outside. :)

Comment: okay i will do the research, one question as well, can achieve this having multiple express apps, say i have 2 express app, one of them is being used as web serve and the other one has function gets data from apis, both use the same db, after it gets data it sets a value to user table, isInitialized = true and in the web server app in angular controller a function checks that isInitialized value and if so loads the data but if not says to user  = " Your dashboard is being prepared"

Comment: You'll have to handle the use-case scenarios accordingly. Checking if the express app is web serve or other function which gets data and then accordingly perform what you need using the service workers.